# Loop only iterates once and doesn't deal with errors yet python

Tags: python, excel

I'm pulling from a an .xlsx list of yahoo tickers and I'm trying to analyse the data, I currently can only get the code to iterate through https://github.com/Benny-/Yahoo-ticker-symbol-downloader list of ticker symbols one at a time. I can't get the code to loop or deal error handling since I'm still relatively new to python.

Let me know what you can help me with and what I can do to improve. Thank you.

```
import yfinance as yf
import openpyxl

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\User\generic.xlsx")
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
r=2
row_num = sheet_obj.max_row
rows = sheet_obj.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=row_num, min_col=1, max_col=2)
try
for row in rows:
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = r, column = 1)
    print(sheet_obj.max_row)
    print(cell_obj.value)


    ticker = yf.Ticker(cell_obj.value)
#try:
    hist=ticker.history(period="max")
#except IndexError:


    sheet_obj.cell(row = r, column = 7).value =hist['Open'].iloc[0]
    maxvalues = hist.max()
    sheet_obj.cell(row = r, column = 8).value = maxvalues.High
    minvalues= hist.min()
    sheet_obj.cell(row = r, column = 9).value = minvalues.Low
#try:
    sheet_obj.cell(row = r, column = 10).value = hist['Close'].iloc[-1]
#except IndexError:
    wb_obj.save("generic.xlsx")

    r = r+1
except IndexError
    Continue
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/

Comment: What is your exact problem? You seems to use `try except` in your code.